# Magento 2.3.3 main.ERROR: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":" No mapping found for ['attribute'] in order to sort on

Tags: magento2.3, upgrade, search, sort, sort-by-options

I have just upgraded to **Magento ver. 2.3.3** (from 2.2.8) with **Elasticsearch** and I am having an issue with my custom module regarding the sort by options.

Elasticsearch information:

```
{
  "name" : "yWDvGWs",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "0L1pnmTiQBaWL21J5p5iPw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.6.12",
    "build_hash" : "cfe3d9f",
    "build_date" : "2018-09-10T20:12:43.732Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

My module contains two plugins as following (di.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="custom_custom_block_toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Toolbar" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="custom_catalog_model_config" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Config" />
    </type>

</config>
```

Here is the plugin for the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar` (Toolbar.php):

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Block;

class Toolbar
{
    public function aroundSetCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $collection
    ) {
    $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
    $result = $proceed($collection);
    if ($currentOrder) {
        if ($currentOrder == 'price_high_to_low') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'desc');
        } elseif ($currentOrder == 'price') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
        } elseif ($currentOrder == 'name') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('name', 'asc');
        } elseif ($currentOrder == 'name_z_a') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('name', 'desc');
        } elseif ($currentOrder == 'news_to_date'){
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('news_to_date', 'desc');
        } elseif ($currentOrder == 'newest_news_to_date'){
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('news_to_date', 'asc');
        } elseif ($currentOrder == 'popularity_by_rating'){
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('popularity_by_rating', 'desc');
        }
    }
    return $result;
    }
}
```

And here is my plugin for `Magento\Catalog\Model\Config` (Config.php):

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model;

class Config
{
    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    $options
    ) {
        $options['price'] = __('Price : Low - High');
        $options['price_high_to_low'] = __('Price : High - Low');
        $options['news_to_date'] = __('Date : Newest');
        $options['newest_news_to_date'] = __('Date : Oldest');
        $options['name'] = __('Name : A-Z');
        $options['name_z_a'] = __('Name : Z-A');
        $options['position'] = __('Our Favourites');
        asort($options);
        return $options;

    }

}
```

The module was working as expected on my Magento ver. 2.2.8 store. After the upgrade, I get this error message on the frontend when trying to filter by the newly added sort by's:

> Sorry, search engine is currently unavailable

I also see this error in the debug.log log file:

```
[2019-11-21 11:39:25] main.ERROR: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [price_high_to_low] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"NJTUipntQBKzkKSBSWTvxg","index":"magento22_product_1_v113"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento22_product_1_v113","node":"yWDvGWsDR2qYSsNUNvZsKg","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [price_high_to_low] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"NJTUipntQBKzkKSBSWTvxg","index":"magento22_product_1_v113"}}]},"status":400} [] []
```

Any help towards fix will be appreciated.

---

***UPDATE***:

Based on the answer, I have upgraded the Elasticsearch to the latest version. This hasn't fixed the problem. This issue still persists. Current Elasticsearch information:

```
{
  "name" : "6WK1xO7",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "5vL1wHvHQt29HWV-xlQ2XQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.8.4",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "bca0c8d",
    "build_date" : "2019-10-16T06:19:49.319352Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.7.2",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: Are you using Elasticsearch?

Comment: I am using Elasticsearch. Edited the question with this additional information.

Comment: please run `bin/magento indexer:reindex` and let me know if you get any errors please

Comment: Indexing hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: I have more or less the same problem. I have the feeling that it is related to if the sorting type is an attribute or not. Like I have a sort filter called "beststellers", but there is no attribute for bestsellers in my store, my filter grabs it right from the database. And I also get this exception....

Answer (score 6):

Custom Sort with ElasticSearch in Magento issue can be fixed by following these simple steps:

- Navigate to **Stores**->**Attributes**->**Product** in Admin.
- **Add New Attribute**.
- In **Properties**->**Attribute Properties**:

  - Add **Default Label** (Eg: Price: Low to High)
  - Select the **Catalog Input Type for Store Owner** (Eg: Price) (In other cases Text Field is enough).
- In **Properties**->**Advanced Attribute Properties**:

  - Add **Attribute Code** (Eg: price_asc).
- In **Storefront Properties**->**Storefront Properties**:

  - Select **User for Sorting in Product Listing** to **Yes**

Once done with the above steps run the following commands,

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext

bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

If you'r facing the same for newest filter sorting issues follow this steps

**Get the attribute_id of 'created_at'**

select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'created_at' and entity_type_id=4;

**Set frontend_label**

update eav_attribute set frontend_label = 'created_at' where attribute_id=112;

**Set used_for_sort_by**

update catalog_eav_attribute set used_for_sort_by = 1 where attribute_id=112;

Comment: `bin/magento indexer:reindex` did not fix but running `bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext` fixed it. Strange.

Comment: not working in 2.4.4

Comment: bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first updating your Elasticsearch, then seeing if this resolves it as Magento claims to support 6.x, and does not recommend versions 2.x and 5.x (albeit providing support).

[...]

Magento Commerce version 2.3.x supports the following Elasticsearch versions:

- Magento 2.3 uses Elasticsearch PHP client version 6.1.

[...]

Please see: [Technologies Magento can use](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#technologies-magento-can-use)

Comment: I will update the Elasticsearch version and update you here. Thanks, useful suggestion.

Comment: I have updated the Elasticsearch, however, I still get the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Run bin/magento indexer:reindex from your root directory folder.