# magento 2.4.3 We can't find products matching the selection

Tags: magento2.4.3

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [pricehighlow] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"AeoPsFB9RvyjSWQH5R5Afw","index":"magento2_product_1_v50"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v50","node":"PNLWW-JIQ6auCGujTUv0Mg","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [pricehighlow] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"AeoPsFB9RvyjSWQH5R5Afw","index":"magento2_product_1_v50"}}]},"status":400} at C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php:675)"} []

Comment: Can you please tell me when it will occur it the sorting is default or you have custom added it by progmatically .

Comment: this is custom add it by progmatically

Comment: Can you post your di.xml , config and toolbar file.

Comment: my code same of this  magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354786/…

Comment: Can you check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296444/magento-2-3-3-main-error-errorroot-causetypequery-shard-exception

and check your elasticsearch version it would 7 or greater than 7

Comment: {
  "name" : "DESKTOP-2R7GTAS",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "92EQgwh9SoGCDW0gJpiesg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.16.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "zip",
    "build_hash" : "2b937c44140b6559905130a8650c64dbd0879cfb",
    "build_date" : "2021-12-18T19:42:46.604893745Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.10.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: that my elasticsearch version details

Comment: this version  also updated  for 7 can give me other solution  please,..

Comment: Have you tried everything mentioned in above link

Comment: yes, i have tried  all things in mention  above  link can you suggest  me anything else.thank  you

Comment: can you find any solution  then suggest  me.thanks you...

Comment: Can you please check https://magento-qa.com/magento-2-4-1-sort-by-newest-not-working this link which have updated some db values after that restart elasticsearch and run magento all commands ( setup:upgrade , di:compile , deploy content and clear cache ) then check once if it works as my issue is solved by this.

Comment: i try it but having problem  can you please  post  your  di.xml , config and toolbar file.

Comment: I have added my files please check can you tell me which filters you want or you can post your files.

Comment: letest price high to low & price  low to high that's fillters i need

Answer (score 0):

Here are the files :

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
    <plugin name="custom_custom_block_toolbar" type="Customsort\Filter\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Toolbar"/>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
    <plugin name="custom_catalog_model_config" type="Customsort\Filter\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Config"/>
</type>
</config>
```

> Toolbar

```
<?php

namespace Customsort\Filter\Plugin\Catalog\Block;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;

class Toolbar
{
const SORT_ORDER_DESC = 'DESC';
protected $_collection = null;
protected $_conn;
protected $_subQueryApplied = false;

public function __construct(ResourceConnection $resource)
{
    $this->_conn = $resource->getConnection('catalog');
}

public function aroundSetCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject, 
\Closure $proceed, $collection) 
{
    $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
    $result = $proceed($collection);
    if($currentOrder)
    {
        if($currentOrder == 'high_to_low')
        {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'desc');
        } 
        elseif ($currentOrder == 'low_to_high')
        {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
        }
        elseif ($currentOrder == 'created_at') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('created_at', 'New');
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $subject->getCollection()->getSelect()->reset('order');
        $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
    }
    return $result;
}

public function afterSetCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
    $result,
    $collection
) {
    $this->_collection = $collection;

    if ($subject->getCurrentOrder() == 'most_viewed') {
        if (!$this->_subQueryApplied) {
            $reportEventTable = $this->_collection->getResource()->getTable('report_event');
            $subSelect = $this->_conn->select()->from(
                ['report_event_table' => $reportEventTable],
                'COUNT(report_event_table.event_id)'
            )->where(
                'report_event_table.object_id = e.entity_id'
            );

            $this->_collection->getSelect()->reset(Select::ORDER)->columns(
                ['views' => $subSelect]
            )->order(
                'views '  . self::SORT_ORDER_DESC
            );

            $this->_subQueryApplied = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
}
```

> Config

```
<?php

namespace Customsort\Filter\Plugin\Catalog\Model;

class Config
{
public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
{
    $options['created_at'] = __( 'Newest' );
    return $options;
}
}
```

Comment: this module is work for magento 2.4.3??

Comment: I have installed  2.4.1 it worked there not checked in 2.4.3

Comment: you use install/update schama setup file??

Comment: can you tall me all file use  for this module

Comment: This module  is working in version<= magento 2.4.1 but  magento 2.4.3 having error like this at time of sorting..... We can't find products matching the selection. and debug file show error as my question can you please guide me for this thank you.